# matching {{string}} in regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

what is the regex for matching a string within two curly brackets as in

```
{{string}}
```

result should be `string`.

Do I have to escape both curly brackets?

Comment: please provide more examples of what should and should not be matched

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, actually the following should work just fine:

```
"{{([^}]*)}}"
```

**Edit:**
As pointed out by *dtb* the expression above fails for a string containing a single `}` within the double brackets. To handle this case the following example would do a much better job:

```
"{{((?:}(?!})|[^}])*)}}"
```

**Edit 2:** The simplest solution however would probably be the following:

```
"{{(.*?)}}"
```

Comment: Very good point, thanks for pointing it out. Updated post with an expression that should take care of this scenario... I hope. ;)

Comment: a much simpler adaptation would be to use `.*?` instead of `[^}]*` - it will not consume the double `}}` because the `?` makes the `*` reluctant, or lazy

Comment: @CodeJockey: Apparently I shouldn't answer regex questions this late. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: or possibly you should switch from decaf?

Comment: @CodeJockey: That I did years ago... didn't help much though, did it. ;)

Comment: No offense (my answer provides for this) but the OP did ask to match "a string _within_ two curly brackets", and specifies that the "result should be `string`". For those that are confused, the expression above will match the string AND the curly brackets, with the string being the first "group" within the match.

Comment: Don't use the .*?, it's very prone to slow expressions and usually a bad advice. It would seem to work, but might allow matches you don't really want. Edit1 is much, much better.

Comment: Is this also possible with [[string]] ?

Answer (score 2):

```
{{string}}
```

:p

or

```
{{(.*)}}
```

only numbers inside the {{ }}

```
{{([0-9])}}
```

only some characters:

```
{{([a-zA-Z])}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"^\{\{(.*?)\}\}$").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would be the best/simplest possible regex to specifically capture the CONTENTS of the curly brackets:

```
(?<={{).*?(?=}})
```

Broken down, this says:

```
01    (?<={{)   # match AFTER two open curly brackets
02    .*?       # match anything, but BE LAZY ABOUT IT
03    (?=}})    # until there are two closing curly brackets
```

With this expression, the ENTIRE match will be the contents of the curly brackets, and the curly brackets will be left in place/ignored

To match the entire curly-bracketed expression, use the following:

```
01    {{        # match two open curly brackets
02    .*?       # match anything, but BE LAZY ABOUT IT
03    }}        # match two closing curly brackets
```

If you want to support multiple lines inside the curly brackets, use `[\s\S]*?` instead of `.*?` in the part on line `02`, or specify the 'singleline' option for the regex parser (DOTALL in Java, etc, etc, etc...).

It does not reject instances like `some text {{{inside}}} other test` and may produce undesired results - if those are possible, please ask for a stronger expression and specify several cases of what should and should not be matched.

Comment: It's `Singleline`, not `Multiline`.  Very common mistake--it comes of expecting the names to make sense. ;)  As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx), `Singleline` changes the meaning of the `.` metacharacter, while `Multiline` changes the meaning of the anchors, `^` and `$`.  Aside from that, this answer looks pretty good to me; not worthy of a downvote.

Comment: indeed - thanks for pointing that out... I would tend to agree about not being worthy of a downvote - but that's the way the cookie crumbles - just get a few people to agree with you and it will look a lot better!

Comment: @Alan - that's also one possible downside of trying to provide a complete answer instead of a 'quick and dirty' answer - not only is it not available for people to read and vote on as long as fast draw answers, it might be more info than the asker needed or wanted, so they'll be here and gone before reading mine... sigh...

Answer (score 1):

```
        string strRegex = @"{{(?<String>\w+)}}";
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);
        string strTargetString = @"\n{{string}}";

       var match = myRegex.Match(strTargetString);

       string str = match.Groups["String"].Value;
```

The str variable will be the string from bracets